# CircularReferenceError when serializing an ActiveRecord instance (fetched by using ThinkingSphinx) to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I try to serialize an instance of my ActiveRecord model to JSON (using "render :json => @entities" or "@entities.to_json"), but I always get an CircularReferenceError ("ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError (object references itself)").
This only happens when the ActiveRecord instances are queried by using ThinkingSphinx. The to_xml serialization works fine. Is that a known problem? I am using the latest Rails 3 and ThinkingSphinx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"render :json => @entities.to_a" works around that problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking Sphinx & Rails 3 & JSON didn't work on my system until I used the following:

```
@entities = Entity.find(:all) 
render :js => @entities.as_json
```

Comment: After changing to "@entities.as_json I'm getting error: SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409

Answer (score 0):

I also get this problem recently, then I change it like the under way

```
render :json => @entities.to_a.to_json(:only => [:entities's attributes], :methods => [:entities's methods])
```

and it works.